# rvest reading a page that is redirected to another URL

Tags: rvest

I would like to get a table in a div from a website with the id `Analysis`. The website I'm trying to access is https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/credit_suisse-aktie. When I manually load the site, it redirects to https://www.finanzen.ch/aktien/credit_suisse-aktie?countryredirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.finanzen.net%2Faktien%2Fcredit_suisse-aktie. If I try reading the first URL with `read_html` the table I'm looking for is not available and the code results in an error

```
require(rvest)
url1 <- "https://www.finanzen.net/aktien/credit_suisse-aktie"
test <- read_html(url1)
test %>% html_element("#Analysis") %>% html_table()
```

If I try it with the second URL it works

```
url2 <- "https://www.finanzen.ch/aktien/credit_suisse-aktie?countryredirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.finanzen.net%2Faktien%2Fcredit_suisse-aktie"
test <- read_html(url2)
test %>% html_element("#Analysis") %>% html_table()
```

So my question is, is there a way to tell `read_html` to follow the redirection of the first URL and only read that page?